# Two MPI computing nodes cannot complete a TCP connection cause by firewall

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mpi, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to run a simple MPI example on two computing nodes `node1` and `node2`, which are virtual machines I just created on Oracle Cloud. (It is the first time I used Oracle Cloud...) The system is Ubuntu 20.04. What I've done include:

- `node1` and `node2` have the correct MPI environment (OpenMPI-4.1.0) under the same path. `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` have also been set. I can successfully run the MPI example on a single node.
- Passwordless login between `node1` and `node2` has been setup. I can use `ssh node1` and `ssh node2` to connect one node to another.
- There is a hostfile (`hosts2`) on the two nodes under the same path (`$HOSTFILE_PATH/hosts2`) containing

```
node1  slots=1
node2  slots=1
```

- The executable files (`test`) are under the same path (`$EXE_PATH/test`).

Then I ran `$(which mpirun) -n 2 -hostfile $HOSTFILE_PATH/hosts2 $EXEC_PATH/test`, and I did not get any return. So I can only terminate the execution with ctrl+c. After I few minutes, I got the output:

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------
A process or daemon was unable to complete a TCP connection
to another process:
  Local host:    instance-1-632783
  Remote host:   instance-1
This is usually caused by a firewall on the remote host. Please
check that any firewall (e.g., iptables) has been disabled and
try again.
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is the problem related to the firewall? I tried `sudo ufw status` and got `Status: inactive`. I also tried `sudo iptables -L`, and got:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:ntp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
InstanceServices  all  --  anywhere             link-local/16       

Chain InstanceServices (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             169.254.0.2          owner UID match root tcp dpt:iscsi-target /* See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             169.254.2.0/24       owner UID match root tcp dpt:iscsi-target /* See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             169.254.4.0/24       owner UID match root tcp dpt:iscsi-target /* See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             169.254.5.0/24       owner UID match root tcp dpt:iscsi-target /* See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             169.254.0.2          tcp dpt:http /* See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule */
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             169.254.169.254      udp dpt:domain /* See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             169.254.169.254      tcp dpt:domain /* See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             169.254.0.3          owner UID match root tcp dpt:http /* See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             169.254.0.4          tcp dpt:http /* See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             169.254.169.254      tcp dpt:http /* See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule */
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             169.254.169.254      udp dpt:bootps /* See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule */
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             169.254.169.254      udp dpt:tftp /* See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule */
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             169.254.169.254      udp dpt:ntp /* See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule */
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             link-local/16        tcp /* See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule */ reject-with tcp-reset
REJECT     udp  --  anywhere             link-local/16        udp /* See the Oracle-Provided Images section in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation for security impact of modifying or removing this rule */ reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Then I tried `sudo iptables -F`, after that, `sudo iptables -L` showed:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain InstanceServices (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

But it seems that `sudo iptables -F` temporarily deletes the policies. When I reboot the system, `sudo iptables -L` shows the former output. So how can I solve the firewall problem? Should I permanently delete the policies? And how?

Comment: Try forcing the interface that allows firewall-less connection between your two instances. For example `mpirun --mca oob_tcp_if_include eth0 --mca btl_btp_if_include eth0 ...`

Comment: Thanks @GillesGouaillardet. I tried `$(which mpirun) -n 2 -hostfile $HOSTFILE_PATH/hosts2 -mca oob_tcp_if_include ens3 --mca btl_btp_if_include ens3  $EXEC_PATH/test`, but it did not work :( . I found the default network card is `ens3` instead of `eth0` via `ifconfig`, so I used `ens3` instead. Is this right?

Comment: that sounds right, the issue is likely a firewall between your hosts. `sudo iptables -L` should not show any rules other than the default `ACCEPT` policy

Comment: After using `sudo iptables -F`, I will get `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain InstanceServices (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination` for `sudo iptables -L`

Comment: that means no firewall is running on the machines. Does Oracle restrict traffic between instances via network firewalls?. on node `n0`, try running `echo hello | nc -l 1234` and on node `n1`, run `nc <ip of n0> 1234 < /dev/null` (expected output is `hello`) to confirm traffic is not restricted between the instances.

Comment: I only know the `sudo iptables -F` command, should I use it? And it seem that `sudo iptables -F` temporarily deletes the policies. When I reboot the system, `sudo iptables -L` shows the original output. The output is not easy to show in the comment, so I edit the original post. Would you mind have a look at it? Thank you for your time.

Comment: there is definitely a firewall running on the nodes, and you do have to deactivate it on **both** nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the VMs are in the same subnet you still have to allow traffic between them.

So open the required ports in the security list of the subnet you are using (https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Concepts/securitylists.htm#Security_Lists)

If you don't know the needed ports you can open all ports (This is not a good practice for production environments).

Comment: Thanks. It actually a problem related to Oracle Cloud. I added an Ingress Rule in the default Security List and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes ufw command does not alter the iptable in OCI. I would recommend you to try iptable command instead. Please refer [linux-iptables-firewall-rules-examples-commands](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-iptables-firewall-rules-examples-commands/) for more commands.

Please use the below command to list all IPv4 rules:

```
sudo iptables -S
```

Comment: Thanks @Anupam Sinha. I tried `sudo systemctl start iptables` and `sudo iptables -F`, then tried to run my MPI program, but it did not work :(

Comment: please check if the required firewall ports are open in the OS level or not. If Not allowed allow it using the iptable command.